# Is there a way to implement google authentication to flutter?

Tags: express, flutter, passport.js

is it valid to use this option to use, far as I understand it, it's just middleware for node.js So, all i need to do is sending a request from mobile app to node.js server.as far as i know A mobile device sending requests to a server is nothing different than a browser sending requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, is it a valid option to use Google authentication in your Flutter app - then yes, indeed this is a valid option. And there are tons of Flutter apps already out there with this option. Top of it, it's too easy to implement. 
Note : You don't have to call your node.js (or other) web app in the browser from Flutter for Google sign in. You can do it natively in Flutter.

Below is a sample code which is taken from [here](https://blog.codemagic.io/firebase-authentication-google-sign-in-using-flutter/).

```
Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, i don't want to implement firebase , i want to use server so i can make my own database

Comment: Firebase auth is just for the simplicity. Otherwise, take a look at - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web By the way, Firebase just provides auth and returns every information of the user after sign-in which you can insert/update to your database.

Comment: And [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) might goes better with node.js

Comment: Google auth comes with firebase